# Change the text on textblock UserControl in VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I created the UserControl which has textblock in VS2010 Express for Windows Phone and added it on the MainPage.xaml. However, I would like to set the text on the the textblock either in codebehind or .xaml file. Would anyone show or give an example or link to me. Thank in advance.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.TitleControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">  

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
 <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,10,28">
  <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"  Style="{StaticResource appTitleStyle}"/>
  <Grid  Height="45" Style="{StaticResource pageTitleBackgroudStyle}">
   <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"     Margin="9,-7,0,17" Style="{StaticResource pageTitleStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Titleqq" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
  <local:TitleControl x:name="Title" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note when writing a usercontrol.

1. Write a class that defines properties in your usercontrol.
2. Bind it to the properties that you wish to expose or set in your windows phone application.

So your Usercontrol would Ideally have,

UserControl.xaml
     UserControl.xaml.cs

You write your class in cs file. Bind it to the properties that you want to set in your application. So in this case you do something like this,

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.TitleControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
x:Name="parent"
>  
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}">
 <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,10,28">
  <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"  Style="{StaticResource appTitleStyle}"/>
  <Grid  Height="45" Style="{StaticResource pageTitleBackgroudStyle}">
   <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"  Text="{Binding Path=Text"}   Margin="9,-7,0,17" Style="{StaticResource pageTitleStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now in your code behind write a class that inherits from UserControl and bind it...
[Link1](http://www.ningzhang.org/2009/11/30/silverlight-design-time-assemblies/) and google on msdn Windows phone UserControl class.
Follow the link->

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, but I am new and not really understand. Is create a new .cs file to create a class or put it on UserControl.cs? Does the property of the class look like this

Comment: http://chris.59north.com/post/Creating-custom-controls-in-Silverlight-part-1.aspx
Can try reading through this article? The basics are just too big to fit in here....

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I still in the dark. If I add the class on my UserControl.xaml.cs.  How can I set the property on my MainPage.xaml? The following code is on my Control.xaml.cs      public TitleControl(Example e) {title=e; InitializeComponent();}public string Caption{get {return title.DisplayText;}

Comment: I found another example to help me out too. There is the link http://alan.beech.me.uk/2011/04/25/adding-a-dependency-property-to-a-wp7-usercontrol/